# Treating 2d array data as pixels defining a shape - is it possible to create an inside and a surface?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, pixel, surface

Say I have the following array/matrix in python (any language will do, to be honest).
    A =

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Is there any easy way to manipulate entries in this array as if they are pixels. Example, would there be any way to create an interior and a surface of arbitrary length, to get, for example:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0
 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
```

Perhaps there is some way to recursively solve this, or maybe in a different way, which would rely on the entries around each element. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check the value and the direct neighborhood of every pixel: Your resulting image is 1 where:

- the original value was 1
- and at least one neighbor is 0

It is 0 everywhere else. The image below might help to illustrate what I mean:

- The center pixel of th red block will stay 1, since it is 1 in the original image and has a neighboring 0.
- The center pixel of the blue block will stay 0, since it was 0in the original image.
- The center pixel of the green block is the interesting case: It was 1 in the original image, but all its neighbors are 1 as well. Thus it becomes 0 in the result.

[image]

Test these conditions for each array entry. Just be careful at the boundaries.

If you have access to an image processing library there is another approach you can take: create a copy of your image, [errode it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_%28morphology%29) by one pixel and subtract it from the original.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you want edge detection. @maddin45 is right, but you could also use scikit-image for this, for example with a canny edge detector:

```python
import numpy as np
from skimage import filters
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = np.array([[0,0,0,0,0],
                [0,1,1,1,0],
                [0,1,1,1,0],
                [0,1,1,1,0],
                [0,0,0,0,0]], dtype=np.float64)

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(filters.canny(arr), interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

[image]